# How to install lightweight desktop environment on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, server

I have a raspberry pi 4, 4GB RAM and have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server edition.As I wanted to make things easy, I installed kubuntu - desktop using:

```
apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

Then I installed tightvnc as I don't have any HDMI cable with me right now.But when I connect VNC, a black screen comes.I searched this on google and found that I have to edit grub and remove "textmode" there.I tried other DE's but it's the same.

I know that Raspberry pi 4 doesn’t support Grub, so how can I install a lightweight Desktop Environment?

*Don't tell me to install ubuntu again with GUI.I don’t want to get into the hassle of installing server components on ubuntu desktop.

Comment: To make things easy, use Raspbian.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.But I am too familiar with Ubuntu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i installed ubuntu-desktop with xserver-xorg and xinit then lightdm

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop lightdm xserver-xorg xinit qv4l2 mumble mumble-server freetuxtv pavucontrol pithos ubuntu-restricted-extras gnome-screenshot took a while

on my pi4

it works great

Answer (score 2):

I would try adding the following to `/boot/firmware/syscfg.txt` (or `usercfg.txt`):

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot properly to the desktop by default on `tty1`. This will allow the boot sequence to complete, and it may fix your issue.